# Load table cell images at same time in objective c

Tags: objective-c

How can I load all table cell images at same time once all images get downloaded asynchronousely using NSURLSession?

```html
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[imageView imageDownloadCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *images) {
                
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   //show images cell.imageview.image =  images[timeinterval];
                });
                
            }];
 
[imageView downloadImages]; 

//download images using NSURLSession. didReceiveResponse sends completion message to show images in above block
            
 }
```

Note. I am using NSURLSession since each table cell contains multiple images which I replace after a time interval.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm reading the question correctly, it sounds like you want to wait until every image has finished downloading before proceeding. You can do that via a dispatch group:

1. At the beginning, create a group via `dispatch_group_create()`.
2. Call `dispatch_group_enter()` before you start each download.
3. In each download's completion block, call `dispatch_group_leave()`.
4. Then, after you start all the downloads, call `dispatch_group_notify()` with the main queue and your completion block. Once every `dispatch_group_enter()` call has been balanced by a `dispatch_group_leave()`, `dispatch_group_notify()` will execute your completion block on the main queue with all your downloads complete.

Comment: Could you please give example for tableview implementation..?